# If line starts with a certain string that match's, and if the following lines are also like that, remove the matched string and merge all lines

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

**Note:** I want to do this in Vscode.

If next line starts with `>` then remove the `>` and merge with the previous line or, in other words, merge everything and remove the leading `>` until the next line found doesn't start with `>`

Example of the multiline citation that i have:

```
Some text

> Some citation    
> and this is the continuation of that citation    
> that should become in one line    

Some other text
```

Would become:

```
Some text

Some citation and this is the continuation of that citation that should become in one line

Some other text
```

Answer (score 0):

- select a `>`
- select all: ctrl-shift-L
- delete '>`: Delete
- join lines: Backspace
- exit multi cursor: Esc

Comment: These steps do not preserve the blank lines between text items and citations or remove the spaces after the `>` well.

Comment: @Mark we need the space to separate the text when we join the lines, with a similar method you can add an extra blank line before a citation.

Comment: So the question is how often the operation is done.  Whether to use the 10 steps or figure out the regex.  But I like your general point of not using a regex when a few simple commands will do the same thing.  If it is done often enough I would save the regex in a snippet and us that.

Answer (score 0):

See https://regex101.com/r/NTZ6gd/3

```
>\s+([^\n]*)((\n)(?!^$)|(\n?))
```

and replace with

```
$1 $4
```

There is some added complexity if the text ends a citation or not.  `>`'s are allowed within the body of the citation.  I don't know if you your citations have spaces at the end of each line so added the space within the replacement.  You can remove that replacement space if there is one space at the end of each citation  line.